# Doctrine join 2 tables query issue

Tags: php, symfony

I got 2 entities - `Product` and `Group`. They are connected as follows:

```
/**
 * Products
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Products
{
   /**
    * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Group
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Group")
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="row_id")
    * })
    */
   public $group;
}
```

So each group may contain many products but 1 product may be connected only to 1 group. I need to select 10 `groups` with all their `products` so the resulting array should contain more than 10 entries as there are definetely more than 1 product per group. I tried the following:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
   $qb->select('g', 'p')
      ->from('AppBundle:Group', 'g')
      ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Products', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.group = g.rowId')
      //->where('p.productnum = g.rowId')
      ->orderBy('g.'.$OrderColumn, $OrderType)
      ->setFirstResult($start)
      ->setMaxResults(10);

$res = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

but I get a mixed array of groups and products (with group as a subelement) and of course there is less than 10 groups in that array (but there are definetely more than 10 groups in my DB) I would like to get an array of 10 groups with products as a subarray to each group. Is that possible? Any Ideas how to do that would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: I think you're confusing what Doctrine returns vs. what a SQL query would normally return.  When you select associated entities you're going to get a single base object, and then all of the associated objects in an `ArrayCollection` underneath it.

Comment: I would like to get it all in one array. I do not want to query all associated objects as it would trigger lazy loading of objects

Comment: Sounds like you want to return an array result or use native SQL then

Comment: If I use `getArrayResult()` I receive an array without associated entities. Any ideas how to get associated entities in it?

Comment: Your original query is getting the associated entities and should work then.  It's just returning in a format that you aren't expecting.  Also you should be able to just use `->leftJoin('AppBundle:Products', 'p')` instead for the join.  You also might want to try selecting from `Products` first and then joining `Groups` second.